# How do I use map with custom function in Octave?

Tags: functional-programming, octave

Assume I have a collection *A*:

```
A = [0:6:100]
```

And I have a function *fib(n)*:

```
function retval=fib(n)
   g1=(1+5^.5)/2
   g2=(1-5^.5)/2
   retval=(1/5^.5)*(g1^n - g2^n)
endfunction
```

I intend to be able to apply *fib(n)* on *A*, and store it in a collection say B, where *B[i,j]* is *(i,fib(i))*, so I can plot *i* vs *fib(i)* and see the results on a graph.

Please advise on how I can use *map* to obtain this desired collection *B*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
map(@fib, A)
```

The `@` makes `fib` into a function handle. Note that `map` is being deprecated and you should use `arrayfun` instead:

```
arrayfun(@fib, A)
```

Comment: The `arrayfun` did it for me (after upgrading to 3.6.2), I didn't have to even install the `miscellaneous ` package to use this (`map` requires it). Thanks

Comment: And if you have a function with several input parameters use this: `arrayfun(@(o) MyFunc(o, 5, 'up'), A)`. In this example with two fixed parameters, a scalar value `5` and a string `'up'`.