# octave map over multiple arguments

Tags: dictionary, octave

I want to map a function that takes two arguments over two vectors of the same length, taking an argument from each of these vectors. I can do it with one argument:

```
map(@sqrt, 1:10)
ans = ....
```

`help map` gives the following example:

```
map(@min, A, B)
ans = ...
```

where `A` and `B` are 2 by 2 matrices, and the result matrix is the element-wise minimum. But when I try this example, I get the following error:

```
A = rand(2,2);
B = rand(2,2);
map(@min, A, B)
error: invalid assignment to cs-list outside multiple assignment.
error: assignment to cell array failed
error: assignment failed, or no method for `<unknown type> = scalar'
error: called from:
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\packages\miscellaneous-1.0.9\map.m at line 108, column 21
```

What am I doing wrong? My system is Win7, 64 bit, and as you can see, my octave version is 3.2.4.

Comment: Works here, Octave version 3.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707464/how-do-i-use-map-with-custom-function-in-octave) question, I was able to find out that `map` is being deprecated, and the correct function to use is `arrayfun`, which works out of the box, both with octave version 3.2.4, which is what I got when downloading a normal windows installer, and with octave version 3.6.2, which I got using cygwin. In version 3.6.2 it even seems that `map` requires the `miscellaneous` package, which `arrayfun` does not.

So I will never know what I did wrong, or if there is a bug (unlikely, given that the function is pretty standard), but my problem was solved by just substituting `arrayfun`:

```
A = rand(2,2);
B = rand(2,2);
arrayfun(@min, A, B)
ans = .... % correct answer
```

Comment: yes. If you look at the code of `map`, you'll see that all it does is pass the arguments to `arrayfun` or `cellfun` (see the source at http://octave.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/octave/trunk/octave-forge/main/miscellaneous/inst/map.m?revision=10964&view=markup ). That's why I deprecated it. It used to be more complex (maybe it was written before `arrayfun`) so you probably had just found a bug on it.

Comment: @carandraug Thanks for the information and for taking time to curate the code base.